# update getters in vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

here I'm trying to edit the data I'm calling using getters .

I created a dynamic form that I will edit the value, I can display the data but I'm still confused about updating the data getters .

this my form edit

[image]

add item here, which is to add 1 row line form

and this my json call by id

```
   {
      "id":"1",
      "name": "Method 0038",
      "desc": "my desc "
      "applied": [
        {
            "item_name": "item 1",
            "item_value": "002"
        },
        {
            "item_name": "item 2",
            "item_value": "003"
        }
      ]
    }
```

this my form

```
<div class="row row g-3" v-for="(applied, row) in getState.applied" :key="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <input type="text" :name="'item ' + row"  v-model="applied.item_name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" :name="'efficiency ' + row" v-model="applied.item_value">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button"  @click="deleteitem(row, applied)">X</button>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-top: 15px;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" @click="addNewRow">Add Item</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

here I call data using getters

```
    computed: {
         getState: {
             return this.$store.getters["dataPro"](this.id)
          }
    },
    methods: {
    deleteitem(row, itm) {
        console.log(itm)
        //here I will remove 1 row, how do I delete that 1 row? it means commit state to update getters
    },
   addNewRow() {
            this.applied.push(
                {
                    item_name : '',
                    item_value: '',
                }
            );
        },
  }
```

**store.js**

```
  state: {
    proyek:[]
  },
  getters: {
    dataPro: (state) => (id) => {
      return state.proyek.find(p => p.id == id);
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_PRO(state,response){
      state.proyek = response.data;
    },
  },
 actions: {
  async GetDataPro({ commit }) {
    commit("SET_PRO", dataJSON);
  },
```

how to remove item and add new item in edit mode ? thnks

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, we have something called **mapGetters**. You can use it as given below

```
<script>
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';
export default {
 computed: {
   ...mapGetters(['dataPro']),
   getState: {
     return this.dataPro(this.id);
   }
 },
 methods: {
  deleteitem(row, itm) {
    console.log(itm)
    //here I will remove 1 row, how do I delete that 1 row? it means  commit state to update getters
  },
  addNewRow() {
    this.applied.push(
       {
         item_name : '',
         item_value: '',
       }
    );
   },
}
</script>
```

for more info check this out: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper